# Grep without storing search to the "/ register in Vim

Tags: vim, grep, cpu-registers

In my `.vimrc` I have a mapping that makes a line of text 'title capitalized':

```
noremap <Leader>at :s/\v<(.)(\w{2,})/\u\1\L\2/g<CR>
```

However, whenever I run this function, it highlights every word that is at least three characters long in my entire document. Of course I could get this behaviour to stop simply by appending `:nohlsearch<CR>` to the end of the mapping, but this is more of an awkward hack that still avoids a bigger problem: The last search has been replaced by `\v<(.)(\w{2,})`.

Is there any way to use the search commands in Vim without storing the last search in the `"/` register; a 'silent' search of sorts? That way, after running this title-making command, I can still use my previous search to navigate the document using `n`, `N`, etc.

### Edit

Using @brettanomyces' answer, I found that simply setting the mapping:

```
noremap <Leader>at :call setline(line('.'),substitute(getline('.'), '\v<(.)(\w{2,})', '\u\1\L\2', 'g'))<CR>
```

will successfully perform the substitution without storing the searched text into the `/` register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some quick experiments I don't think there is a way not to store the last search in the `/` register. You can however create a function which saves the value of the `/` register before performing the substitute then restores it afterwards.

e.g.

```
noremap <Leader>at :call CapTitle()<cr>

function! CapTitle()
  let l:prev_search = @/
  call setline(line('.'),substitute(getline('.'), '\v<(.)(\w{2,})', '\u\1\L\2', 'g'))
  let @/ = l:prev_search
endfunction
```

Comment: Actually, if you just set the mapping to the `call` line, the search isn't stored in a register!